# How to change default ajax loading icon in magento 2 checkout page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento, magento2

I want to change spinner at checkout page of magento 2 to some icon or gif, is it possible to change?

[Ajax Loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9aLr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this would be to just override the `loader-1.gif` in your own theme.

Place a new gif in the `web/images` folder of your theme with the name `loader-1.gif`. So should have a file in `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/images/loader-1.gif`.

You may need to go to the same folder within `pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/locale/images` and remove the symlink to the base gif before it shows at it will still link to old file.